how to prevent sql injection in snowflake filter function
Im using input from the user to query snowflake within DRF view, how to prevent in the below code sql injection possibility?
entity_id = kwargs['pk']
table = session.table("my_table").filter(col(ID_COL)==entity_id )


Can't you use 'path/<int:pk>'?

Why do you think there is even an injection risk here?

The id is a string, not an integer.
@Tim Biegeleisen, I tried to find out something explicit in the documetnation but didnt find.

@LiorA Most likely, your builder code is internally being backed by a prepared statement, so injection is not a real concern.

The builder in the snowpark API you meant?. but nothing explicit is mentioned, so we one cant be sure its protecting against injection.. maybe I missing something?

The good news is that the user input should be already filtered if you are using filter().
Testing with Snowpark:
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.
    tableName = 'information_schema.packages'
    dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("language") == "';drop table bobby_tables")

    # Print a sample of the dataframe to standard output.
    dataframe.show()

    # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
    return dataframe

If you go check the Snowflake logs, you'll find that Snowflake ran the following query, with the quote escaped:
SELECT  *  
FROM information_schema.packages 
WHERE ("LANGUAGE" = ''';drop table bobby_tables')


Thanks, really think they should write something about it in the snowflake documentation.
